# Play2, Scala, Slick3

Tags: scala, playframework, slick

I'm writing a simple web application with MySql, Deadbolt2 and slick3.
I currently stuck with something blocking MySql database.

> MySQL said: Documentation
>   1040 - Too many connections

I am using Table.scala automatically generated model from slick

Connection established in DAO file:

```
val db = Database.forConfig("db_tfl")
val users: TableQuery[Users] = TableQuery[Users]
val roles: TableQuery[Roles] = TableQuery[Roles]
```

And this would be DAO function called from Controller

```
def test() = {
  db.run {
    users += UsersRow(0, None, Option("Stefan"), Option("Zeiger")))     
  }
}
```

After calling it 5; 6 times I have MySql Too many connections error.
What would be the cause ?

Comment: Basically, you need to be doing something more to ensure that previous connections are closed properly when not in use. Database interactions should be closed as soon as possible to avoid hitting your database server's limit on concurrent connections.

Comment: The real question is: Why aren't your connections closing?